# Tools for Bounded, Continuous, Black-box Global Optimization with Gradient Information?

Tags: optimization, nonlinear-optimization, non-convex-optimization

I want to find the global minimum of a potential energy surface with readily accessible gradients, though there is no closed form expression for this function. This function is known to be non-convex. I'm aware of stochastic methods for global optimization, like simulated annealing and genetic algorithms, but ideally I'd like a deterministic method that guarantees I find the global minimum.

There were a couple options I found, but these methods typically involve knowing the functional form of the objective function such that you can find bounds on the gradient/Hessian over an interval.

Are there deterministic algorithms that find the global optimum for black-box bounded functions with gradients?